# How to pass string address to leaflet routing machine to get direction based on string address?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Well, I am using leaflet api and then I found a very nice supporting plugin called leaflet routing machine for showing address from A to B with nice route.

However, leaflet routing machine working fine with passing of latlng but not working with passing address so can anyone tell how it can work as I know property information on following link:
[So routing waypoint have property called name but don;t know how to use it to provide address a and address B](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-waypoint)

Here is a code which shows new Zealand Auckland city....and trying to pass address but doesn't work

```
< script >

  var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    center: [-36.85625, 174.76141],
    zoom: 13
  });

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.yourkey', {

  attribution: 'Log Sample',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);
//L.Control.geocoder().addTo(mymap);
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    //L.latLng(-36.87178, 174.753),
    //L.latLng(-36.84514, 174.76493)
    L.name("12 Morning Star place, Auckland"),
    L.name("198 Dominion road, Mount Roskill, Auckland")
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: false
}).addTo(mymap); < /script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as remember you can pass `L.Routing.Waypoint` object to `waypoints` as well.

So, your code would look like:

```
....
var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()

L.Routing.control({
  geocoder: geocoder,
  waypoints: [
    //L.latLng(-36.87178, 174.753),
    //L.latLng(-36.84514, 174.76493)
    L.Routing.waypoint(null,"12 Morning Star place, Auckland"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(null,"198 Dominion road, Mount Roskill, Auckland")
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: false,
}).addTo(mymap);
```

But this again doesn't geocode it. Instead just populates waypoints textboxes. You still need to hit enter (or trigger it by js) on each of the boxes to run geocoder.

Another option would be manually grabbing data from geocoder and create `L.Routing.Waypoint` or `L.LatLng` object before setting waypoints

```
geocoder.geocode('Montreal', function(a, b) {
    // depending on geocoder results may be either in a or b 
    console.log(a);
    // choose the best result here. probably the first one in array
    // create waypoint object
    var wpt = L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(lat, lng), name)
    waypoints.push(wpt);
})

...

// setting waypoints
routingControl.setWaypoints(waypoints);
```

#### Update to cover question in comments

The custom markers with popup could be added via `L.Routing.Plan`. Your `L.Routing.control` object could be initialized like so:

```
var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    waypoints = [], // can be populated later
    routeControl = L.Routing.control({
        plan: L.Routing.plan(waypoints, {
                createMarker: function(i, wp) {
                    return L.marker(wp.latLng, {
                        draggable: true
                    }).bindPopup("Some data for popup");
                },
            geocoder: geocoder,
            routeWhileDragging: false,
        })
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi first of all thank you so much for reply and secondly, I tried both of your code but I need help for second part of code which I tried but didn't work so can you please provide me jsfiddle or full working code so that I can have a look where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't have time to clean it up (handle callbacks, format, etc...) So, quick and dirty [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4yfy4ek/114/) but working. Eventually you will see markers

Comment: Thank you so much for this as it's work and I tick as you have given me answer. Secondly, apart from this do you know any way to add custom popup boxes to each of this markers???

Comment: Updated the answer ;)

Comment: Hey bro, seriously you are awesome and in fact too good:) Thanks a lot as it saves my day. Bro if you don't mind I have a last question hopefully, as still amazed that how I can bindpopup with different messages according to different markers.....but if you are so busy to help me out this then it's fine as I think genius like you must be busy but if you can help would be really appreciated. Thanks:) once again you are too good.

Comment: Thanks! for your last question there are many solutions. the simplest would be keeping two separate arrays (one with lat/lng, the other with messages) in the same order, so e.g. `waypoins[3]` has message in `messages[3]`. Then you can just use `i` variable (stands for waypoint's index) in the  `createMarker` function