# Leafletjs L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(), Button to run the code

Tags: leaflet

I need a working exemple please, because this cod generates  textboxes without a  button to run the code.So how can get the button to run the code?

```js
var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim();

L.Routing.control({
geocoder: geocoder,
waypoints: [
    L.latLng(null, "here my current position, data from GPS"),
    L.latLng(null, "here address as string, input from the user")
],
show: false,

routeWhileDragging: false,

}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass string address to leaflet routing machine to get direction based on string address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062782/how-to-pass-string-address-to-leaflet-routing-machine-to-get-direction-based-on)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062782/how-to-pass-string-address-to-leaflet-routing-machine-to-get-direction-based-on

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a geocoding service to transform textual addresses into coordinate pairs. See http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding